# How to automatically add text to image on hover

Tags: css

I have an image that I would like to add text to. I don't know what the best method would be. I have seen the map tag in HTML but I don't know if that helps me. For each individual part of the image, I'd like to add a text next to it on hover.

My best solution so far is to make a div with the image as a background image, and have multiple spans for each part of my image, but that stopped working precisely when rescaling the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet for you.

```js
$('.hover-with-caption').on('mousemove',function(e){     
  
   $('#dynamicCaption').remove();
   $('body').append("<span id='dynamicCaption' class='dynamic-caption'></span>");
   $('#dynamicCaption').text('what ever you want to show here!! '+event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY); // you need to decide what to show and how you are going to generate the caption, As you have not given mush info about it.
   
    $('#dynamicCaption').finish().toggle(100).
            css({
                top: e.pageY + "px",
                left: e.pageX + "px"
            });    
  
   $(document).off("click.customCaption").on("click.customCaption", function (e) {
            // alert('context menu other mouse events');
            if (!$(e.target).parents('#dynamicCaption').length > 0) {
                $('#dynamicCaption').remove();                
            }
        });   
});
```

```css
div.parent{
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  position: relative;           
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor:pointer;
}


img{
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
}

.dynamic-caption {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<img class="hover-with-caption" src="http://cdn.codeproject.com/App_Themes/CodeProject/Img/logo250x135.gif" />

</div>
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but unfortunately this doesn't help me out. I need to add individual captions to each part of the image, not as a whole. right now, I'll try to register the mouse position on hover over areas of a html map and add text at that spot via jquery. It's not exactly how I wanted it to be done but it isnt worse.

Comment: `I need to add individual captions to each part of the image, not as a whole. right now` So you say you have a image and on hover of the image  depending on the position of the mouse you need to show a text?

Comment: @MartinHoffmann I have edited my post, Check the snippet and let me know if this helps.